# Bootcamp and Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, mac, 64-bit, boot-camp

I was wondering if windows 7 64bit would work with bootcamp?

Please don't just say yes unless you've tried it or know someone who has.

I am going to order an OEM Disc this week and need to know whether I should get 32bit or 64bit.

Thanks

Comment: The OEM discs have special licensing that would likely not apply to the senerio of Boot Camp.  http://oem.microsoft.com/public/sblicense/2008_sb_licenses/fy08_sb_license_english.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, I've seen people do it. Check if you have a compatible Mac though, the supported models can be found in the [Apple Knowledgebase](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1846):

> These Macs can use 64-bit editions of
>   Windows Vista and Windows 7:
>
> - MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2009) and later
> - MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2008) and later
> - MacBook Pro (17-inch, Early 2008) and later
> - Mac Pro (Early 2008) and later
> - iMac (21.5 inch, Late 2009)
> - iMac (27-inch, Late 2009)
> - iMac (27-inch, Quad Core, Late 2009)
> - MacBook (13-inch, Late 2009) and later
> - iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2010)
> - iMac (27-inch, Mid 2010)
> - Mac mini (Mid 2010)
>
> These Macs support only 32-bit or
>   64-bit editions of Windows 7 and do
>   not support Windows Vista or Windows
>   XP.
>
> - MacBook Air (11-inch, Late 2010)
> - MacBook Air (13-inch, Late 2010)

Comment: Yup. I install Windows 7 x64 on macbooks several times a week. The only thing we often have trouble with is graphics drivers - you may need to download them from Nvidia directly - the ones included with the bootcamp installer don't seem to work on some of the newer models.

Comment: Got i working Had absolutely no problems and the graphic driver work fine.Cheers